# Is it possible to stop a Heroku Daily Dyno Restart for a Hobby Dyno

Tags: heroku

Is it possible to stop a Heroku Daily Dyno Restart for a Hobby Dyno?

My Goal is to stop the Dyno from restarting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, **No** (with an aside that the restart shouldn't be seen as a bad thing).

From the [Heroku Dynos and Dyno Manager Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting)

> **Dynos are also restarted (cycled) at least once per day to help maintain the health of applications** running on Heroku. Any changes to the local filesystem will be deleted. The cycling happens once every 24 hours (plus up to 216 random minutes, to prevent every dyno for an application from restarting at the same time).
>
> **Cycling happens for all dynos**, including one-off dynos, so dynos will run for a maximum of 24 hours + 216 minutes.
>
> **In addition, dynos are restarted as needed for the overall health of the system and your app.** For example, the dyno manager occasionally detects a fault in the underlying hardware and needs to move your dyno to a new physical location.

Additionally, Dynos Restart if you:

- create a new release by deploying new code
- change your config vars
- change your add-ons
- run heroku restart

With Hobby Dynos, the real issue is that inactivity causes the Dyno to sleep throughout the day. From my personal experience, waking up a sleeping dyno can cause a page to take ~30s to load.

There are many solutions to 'ping' the dyno on regular intervals to keep it 'awake'.

An example solution for a Node Server is [`heroku-self-ping`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heroku-self-ping)